# Why is there no retraction between $D^2 \times S^1$ and $S^1\times S^1$?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

Why is there no retraction between $D^1 \times S^1$ and $S^1\times S^1$?

I have no idea how to prove. I just know that if there is then $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ contains a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$.

This works: (?)

Let $i$ the inclusion of $S^1\times S^1$ on $D^2 \times S^1.$ Then $r \circ i = \operatorname{id}.$ Then, there are the following chain:

$$\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$$

and that is the problem!

Comment: If $X\to Y$ is a retract then $\pi_1(X)\to\pi_1(Y)$ is onto. But $\Bbb Z$ doesn't surject onto $\Bbb Z^2$.

Comment: Well, you can also prove that no group homomorphism $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z$ is injective. For instance, $$f(-f(0,1),f(1,0))=0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $r : D^2\times S^1 \to S^1\times S^1$ is a retract, then $r\circ i = \operatorname{id}_{S^1\times S^1}$ where $i : S^1\times S^1 \to D^2\times S^1$ is the inclusion map. Let $p \in S^1\times S^1 \subset D^2\times S^1$ and note that the maps $i$ and $r$ induce maps on homotopy groups

$$\pi_1(S^1\times S^1, p) \xrightarrow{i_*} \pi_1(D^2\times S^1, p) \xrightarrow{r_*} \pi_1(S^1\times S^1, p).$$

As $\pi_1(S^1\times S^1, p) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$ and $\pi_1(D^2\times S^1, p) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, we see that

$$\mathbb{Z}^2 \xrightarrow{i_*} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{r_*} \mathbb{Z}^2.$$

As $r_*\circ i_* = (r\circ i)_* = (\operatorname{id}_{S^1\times S^1})_* = \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{Z}^2}$, we see that $i_*$ is injective and $r_*$ is surjective.

If $r_* : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}^2$ were surjective, then by the first isomorphism theorem $\mathbb{Z}/\ker r_* \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$ but this is impossible as the only quotients of $\mathbb{Z}$ are $\mathbb{Z}$ and finite cyclic groups. Therefore, there is no retraction.